# Sum of fifth roots of roots of cubic.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b,c$ are the (real) roots of $x^3-16x^2-57x+1=0$. Prove that
$\sqrt[5]{a} + \sqrt[5]{b} +\sqrt[5]{c} = 1 $

................................................................................

edit : my answer to this question on another forum

Let $p=\sqrt[5]{a},q=\sqrt[5]{b}, r=\sqrt[5]{c}, u=p+q+r, v=qr+rp+pq, w=pqr$

From given cubic p⁵+q⁵+r⁵=16, q⁵r⁵+r⁵p⁵+p⁵q⁵=-57, p⁵q⁵r⁵=-1 (so w=-1)
Thus results at end gives the following simultaneous equations for u,v

p⁵+q⁵+r⁵ = 16 = u⁵-5u³v+5uv²-5u²+5v 
q⁵r⁵+r⁵p⁵+p⁵q⁵ = -57 = v⁵+5uv³+5u²v+5v²+5u

I solved these via Mathematica to give u=1, v=-2 (only real solution) so your answer is 1

====================

p,q,r are roots of z³-uz²+vz-w=0

Multiply by zⁿ and let s(n)=pⁿ+qⁿ+rⁿ

Set z=p,q,r in turn and sum for the recurrence s(n+3) = us(n+2)-vs(n+1)+ws(n)

Noting that s(0)=3, s(1)=u, s(2)=u²−2v generate s(3), s(4), s(5) as follows …

n=0 : s(3) = us(2)-vs(1)+ws(0) = u³-3uv+3w

n=1 : s(4) = us(3)-vs(2)+ws(1) = u⁴-4u²v+2v²+4uw

n=2 : s(5) = us(4)-vs(3)+ws(2) = u⁵-5u³v+5uv²+5u²w-5vw

p⁵+q⁵+r⁵ = u⁵-5u³v+5uv²+5u²w-5vw

Replace p by qr, q by rp, r by pq and get

q⁵r⁵+r⁵p⁵+p⁵q⁵ = v⁵-5uv³w+5u²vw²+5v²w²-5uw³

====================

Comment: @molarmass OP made an edit.

Comment: $x^{15}-16x^{10}-57x^5+1$ factors as

Hint: $(x^3-x^2-2x+1)(x^{12}+x^{11}+3x^{10}+4x^9+9x^8-2x^7+12x^6-x^5+25x^4+11x^3+5x^2+2x+1)$ and the sum of the roots of the first factor is $1$.

Comment: Why is this closed ? The OP did show some non-trivial effort, even though presented via an uncommon medium.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In that link I only see efforts that others have done to answer his question.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: the first answer is by the OP himself. Check the signatures.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, right. The person who asked the question there is not  the person who asked it here. Confusing.

Comment: @urchin You should reproduce your solution here, as this creates confusion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - thanks - I never thought I'd get anywhere with trying to factor a 15th degree polynomial ! However, the question remains of how to do this for a cubic with real roots that leads to a 15th degree equation without a cubic factor with rational coefficients.

Comment: @URCHIN: if your question gets unlocked, I can explain a simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A,B,C$ be the roots of the cubic polynomial
$$
g(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1\ .
$$
So $A,B,C$ satisfy (Vieta):
$$
\begin{aligned}
e_1 &=A + B + C &&=+1\ ,\\
e_2 &= AB + BC + CA &&=-2\ ,\\
e_3 &= A B C &&= -1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(Computer support motivating the above is postponed.)
These values are numerically:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: g = x^3 - x^2 - 2*x + 1
sage: g(x).roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False)
[-1.246979603717467?, 0.4450418679126288?, 1.801937735804839?]
```

so they are real.
We compute the polynomial with roots $a'=A^5$, $b'=B^5$, $c'=C^3$.

(We "hope" that $a=a'$, $b=b'$, $c=c'$.)

For this we have to start computations involving symmetrical polynomials, 
trying to get 
$e_1(a',b',c')$, 
$e_2(a',b',c')$, 
$e_3(a',b',c')$, in terms of $e_1(A,B,C)$, $e_2(A,B,C)$, $e_3(A,B,C)$.
Here, $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ are the first three symmetric polynomials.
(We have formally $e_4=e_5=\dots=0$.)

One result is immediate:
$$
e_3(a',b',c')
=a'b'c'
=A^5B^5C^5=(ABC)^5=e_3(A,B,C)^5=-1\ .
$$
We need now the Newton polynomial $p_5$ in [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) of fifth degree...
$$
\begin{aligned}
e_1(a',b',c')
&=
a'+b'+c'
\\
&=A^5+B^5+C^5
\\
&=p_5(A,B,C)\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{so we compute successively}\\
p_1(A,B,C) &= e_1(A,B,C)=1\ ,\\
p_2(A,B,C) &= (e_1p_1-2e_2)(A,B,C)=1\cdot 1-2\cdot(-2)=5\ ,\\
p_3(A,B,C) &= (e_1p_2-e_2p_1+3e_2)(A,B,C)=1\cdot 5-(-2)\cdot1+3\cdot(-1)=4\ ,\\
p_4(A,B,C) &= (e_1p_3-e_2p_2+e_3p_1)(A,B,C)=1\cdot 4-(-2)\cdot5+(-1)\cdot1=13\ ,\\
e_1(a',b',c') &=p_5(A,B,C)
\\&=(e_1p_4-e_2p_3+e_3p_2)(A,B,C)=1\cdot13-(-2)\cdot4+(-1)\cdot5=16\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We need now finally $a'b'+b'c'+c'a'$.
For this, we repeat the same procedure as above, but not for $A,B,C$, but for $s,t,u$, which are respectively $AB$, $BC$, $CA$, with
$$
\begin{aligned}
e_1(s,t,u) &=s+t+u=AB + BC + CA &&=-2\ ,\\
e_2(s,t,u) &=st+tu+us= ABC(A+B+C) &&=-1\ ,\\
e_3(s,t,u) &=stu= A^2 B^2 C^2 &&= +1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1(s,t,u)&=e_1(s,t,u)=-2\ ,\\
p_2(s,t,u)&=(e_1p_1-2e_2)(s,t,u)=(-2)\cdot (-2)-2\cdot(-1)=6\ ,\\
p_3(s,t,u)&=(e_1p_2-e_2p_1+3e_2)(s,t,u)=(-2)\cdot6-(-1)\cdot(-2)+3\cdot1=-11\ ,\\
p_4(s,t,u)&=(e_1p_3-e_2p_2+e_3p_1)(s,t,u)
=(-2)\cdot(-11)-(-1)\cdot6+1\cdot(-2)=26\ ,\\
e_2(a',b',c')&=p_5(s,t,u)
\\
&=(e_1p_4-e_2p_3+e_3p_2)(s,t,u)
=(-2)\cdot26-(-1)\cdot(-11)+1\cdot6=-57\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $a',b',c'$ are the roots of the given polynomial
$$
x^3-E_1x^2+E_2x-E_3
=
x^3 - 16x^2 -57 x +1\ .
$$
So $a',b',c'$ are (up to reordering) the "given" values $a,b,c$.
We conclude:
$$
a^{1/5} + b^{1/5} + c^{1/5}
=A+B+C=1\ .
$$

### $\square$

Numerical support for the computations done so far, and the motivation for the abrupt start with the roots $A,B,C$ of the polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$:

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) code:

```
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
f = x^3  - 16*x^2 - 57*x + 1
a, b, c = f.roots( ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False )
a, b, c
a^(1/5), b^(1/5), c^(1/5)
```

This gives:

```
(-3.015065490237851?, 0.01745839634379104?, 18.99760709389406?)
(1.008827691046369? + 0.7329562209746396?*I,
 0.4450418679126288?,
 1.801937735804839?)
```

OK, the computer needs human assitance to get the right fifth root of $a$ in $\Bbb R$.

```
 A, B, C = -(-a)^(1/5), b^(1/5), c^(1/5)
```

giving

```
sage: A, B, C
(-1.246979603717467?, 0.4450418679126288?, 1.801937735804839?)
```

this is good, three real numbers. Let us compute the elementary symmetric functions,
and the first Newton polynomials for them:

```
print "A + B + C    = %s" % (A+B+C)
print "AB + BC + CA = %s" % (A*B + B*C + C*A) 
print "A B C        = %s" % (A*B*C)

for k in [1..5]:
    print "A^%s + B^%s + C^%s = %s" % (k, k, k, A^k+B^k+C^k)
```

This gives so far:

```
A + B + C    = 1.000000000000000?
AB + BC + CA = -2.000000000000000?
A B C        = -1.000000000000000?
A^1 + B^1 + C^1 = 1.000000000000000?
A^2 + B^2 + C^2 = 5.000000000000000?
A^3 + B^3 + C^3 = 4.000000000000000?
A^4 + B^4 + C^4 = 13.00000000000000?
A^5 + B^5 + C^5 = 16.00000000000000?
```

Same for the values $s,t,u$:

```
s, t, u = A*B, B*C, C*A

print "s + t + u    = %s" % (s+t+u)
print "st + tu + us = %s" % (s*t + t*u + u*s) 
print "s t u        = %s" % (s*t*u)

for k in [1..5]:
    print "s^%s + t^%s + u^%s = %s" % (k, k, k, s^k+t^k+u^k)
```

This gives:

```
s + t + u    = -2.000000000000000?
st + tu + us = -1.000000000000000?
s t u        = 1.000000000000000?
s^1 + t^1 + u^1 = -2.000000000000000?
s^2 + t^2 + u^2 = 6.000000000000000?
s^3 + t^3 + u^3 = -11.00000000000000?
s^4 + t^4 + u^4 = 26.00000000000000?
s^5 + t^5 + u^5 = -57.00000000000000?
```

Comment: The auxiliary cubic polynomial is readily obtained as a factor of $p(x^5)$ where $p$ is the original cubic.

Comment: Yes, as in the comments to the OP. My problem was to see its roots and the fact that they are real. Else one has to take the suitable branch of the fifth root. to match this one "beautiful factor". People wanted computations explicitly, i did it explicitly. On a piece of paper with own notations the calculus is done in some five minutes, typing all the stuff...

Comment: Computationally we can simply go with `(-(-a)^(1/5) + b^(1/5) + c^(1/5)).minpoly()`, which tells us that it's the root of `x-1`, i.e. it equals 1.

Answer (score 3):

The given polynomial $p(x)$ has three real roots so $p(x^5)$ also has three real roots as all others are complex fifth roots of reals.

So we need to factor $p(x^5)=q(x)r(x)$ where $q$ is cubic with real roots and $r$ is an unimportant polynomial of degree twelve with complex ones.

With a simple numerical solver or with Cardano's formulas, we estimate the coefficients of $q$ using Vieta's formulas on the fifth roots of $p$, giving

$$q(x)\approx (x-1.80194) (x-0.445042) (x+1.24698)\\\approx x^3-1.000002 x^2-2.000002633x+1.000001871.$$

So we can hypothetize $q(x)=x^3-x^2-2x+1$ and *long division confirms this hypothesis exactly* *.

Then the sum of the real roots of $q$ is $1$.

---

*$$\dfrac{x^{15}-16x^{10}-57x^5+1}{x^3-x^2-2x+1}\\=x^{12}+x^{11}+3x^{10}+4x^9+9x^8-2x^7+12x^6-x^5+25x^4+11x^3+5x^2+2x+1.$$

Comment: Yes, a useful trick. Wolfram will also factor p(x⁵) directly, which is something |I should have tried.

Comment: @URCHIN: the next challenge is to find a way to solve fully by hand.