# Finding sum of some fractional powers(1/5) of root of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do we have some proper method to find sum of roots of the root of P(x)? 
Like say 
we have P(x) =$ x^3 -16x^2 + 57x+1$ 
say its root are a,b, c 
for finding $ a^{1/5} + b^ {1/5} +c^{1/5} $
do we have some method or i need to take power 5 and 
solve manipulating the terms ?

Comment: Interesting. I would think there might be some results as an application of [vieta's formula's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x29fcpfahk

Comment: No. I would think that there is not a general method of doing this: You will have to compute the roots and then compute the powers. For a polynomials with degree less than $4$ there is a formula for finding the roots: and thereby there is a formula for the sum of the roots raised to some power. For higher degree polynomials there is not a formula for this.

Comment: so here can we find the value?

Comment: Very similar to [Sum of fifth roots of roots of cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884449/sum-of-fifth-roots-of-roots-of-cubic).

Comment: yes. almost duplicate. cant we solve completely by hands